# Binding parameterized query failing when SQL invariant data format used

Tags: r, odbc, r-dbi

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to bind a parameterized query with dates in the SQL invariant format 'YYYYMMDD' (see full example below):

```
# Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params, batch_rows): nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 22018: 
# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification
```

The error thrown seems to indicate an error casting the strings into date format in nanodbc. I've reviewed the nanodbc [documentation](https://nanodbc.github.io/nanodbc/index.html), but couldn't find any reference to permitted date formats.

These parameters are bound successfully when an alternate date format is used ('YYYY-MM-DD'):

```
library(DBI)

my_conn <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), driver = "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server", 
                     database = db, server = server)

query <- "SELECT myvar FROM dbo.myTable WHERE myvar BETWEEN ? AND ?"
interim_res <- DBI::dbSendQuery(my_conn, query)

dbBind(interim_res, list("20210101", "20211231") # does not work, throws error below

# Error in result_bind(res@ptr, params, batch_rows): nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 22018: 
# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification

dbBind(interim_res, list("2021-01-01", "2021-12-31") # this date format works
```

Could someone please help me understand why dates in the format 'YYYYMMDD' fail to be bound?

TIA!

Comment: `nanodbc`'s documentation will not be authoritative, you need to refer to docs for the specific DBMS; `nanodbc` just simplifies the conduit between you and the database, it isn't doing the SQL or data interpretation.

Comment: While postgres supports `YYYYMMDD` (I was surprised to discover this), mssql does not. Is there a problem with using `YYYY-MM-DD` in your queries? In my experience it really is the standard and most-widely understood.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  No, not a huge deal I was mostly interested in understanding the source of the error. Possibly a gap in my understanding, but I can submit queries with dates in the `YYYYMMDD` format when querying directly through the mssms application. Is there some other parsing applied to the string there?

Comment: I am confident that `nanodbc` and `DBI`/`odbc` do no parsing/interpretation of the data, I cannot speak for mssms, sorry, but if you can get that query to work with the same database, then it sounds like it may be doing that for you.